# Per-site metas don't have ability of suggested-edits

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, suggested-edits, per-site-meta

I love the [suggested-edits feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-does-peer-review-for-edits-work/76284#76284) that was recently added onto Stack Exchange. However, this feature seems to be missing in per-site metas.

For instance:

**Server Fault Meta:**

[image: server fault screenshot]

**DBA Meta**

[image: dba screenshot]

The parent websites, do have the edit/improve this post link however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87890/why-cant-i-suggest-edits-on-se-meta-sites/97371#97371) -- we don't think the metas need this feature.

Comment: This is perhaps the first time you've said something was "by design" and I agreed that it should be done that way.

Comment: Just this one occasion I needed to edit a Meta post, left a comment for it anyway.