# Why can't I suggest edits on SE meta sites?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, per-site-meta

When you click "edit" on a meta site as a non-edit-privileged user, the error message appears:

> Suggested edits are not allowed on non-tag-wiki posts on meta sites.

Right as I was going to post this as a possible bug, I finally found [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78223/per-site-metas-dont-have-ability-of-suggested-edits/78319#78319) which says that per-site Metas don't have suggested edits by-design because it's "not needed".

However, I've been participating a lot over at [Skeptics meta](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/) where there is a lot still to be figured out in terms of site guidelines.  The Meta is one of the most active I've seen and a lot of the questions are really trying to gather community-built suggestions.  So maybe more of those need to be Community Wiki, but it still brings me to ask **why** don't per-site-metas "need" suggested edits?

**Adding bounty**: The more betas I participate in, the more I don't get this.

Comment: This just feels wrong to me in 2014 with all the improvements to review tools and the number of moderators that are around. The post saying low traffic -> edit can't be moderated seems backwards to me. When you have a beta site with low traffic, you need every person that cares to try to edit a post and contribute and not turn people away. I've asked for [this edit ban to be repealed on beta sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223885/allow-suggested-edits-on-per-site-metas), so let's see if that is a safer change than this to start with.

Comment: Having more than 1000 rep allows a person to edit per site meta as well

Comment: 1000 only in beta site, it's 2000 on graduated sites. And this whole discussion is about *suggested edits* anyway.

Comment: @bmike Thanks for this. I like to edit and feel like it's especially important to keep meta posts clean, as they're often active for years. Unfortunately, I asked in the SE Meta chat today if there had been any change to that policy and they said no. It wasn't somebody I know so I didn't ask for explanation, but I think it's too bad.

Comment: This is even more strange when you realize that <2000 users *can* suggest edits to tag wikis on Meta sites.

Comment: Why not simply remove the ‘edit’ link? It prevents the confusion.

Comment: Related: [Allow suggested edits on site metas and show them in the main site queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129033/162827)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

### Meta review queues should be integrated into the main site's review

Low meta participation is a problem.  Since a policy is decided in meta, it can be discouraging to discover that people don't know about meta or simply ignore it.  But even as a meta-junkie, I was surprised to see that there *is* a suggested edit queue on the per-site-metas... for tag wikis.  For obvious reasons, this is rarely populated.

At any rate, if the only reason for not allowing suggested edits is the limited number of people who will be able to review them, why not implement the suggestion made by [Paŭlo Ebermann](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87890/why-cant-i-suggest-edits-on-se-meta-sites#comment282752_97371) and [Kevin Vermeer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87890/why-cant-i-suggest-edits-on-se-meta-sites#comment283933_97371)?

Here is a mock-up (sans the dynamic bits):

> **Close Votes**
>   Vote whether or not to close questions with close votes
>
> **Late Answers**
>   Review late answers from new users
>
> **First Posts**
>   Review first posts from new users
>
> **Low Quality Posts**
>   Identify, then improve or delete low-quality posts
>
> **Reopen Votes**
>   Vote whether or not to reopen closed questions with reopen votes
>
> **Suggested Edits**
>   Approve, reject, or improve edits suggested by users
>
> ---
>
> **Meta Close Votes**
>   Vote whether or not to close meta questions with close votes
>
> **Meta Reopen Votes**
>   Vote whether or not to reopen closed meta questions with reopen votes
>
> **Meta Suggested Edits**
>   Approve, reject, or improve edits suggested by users

Comment: Why separate meta X from X? And while you're at it, I'd like [mod flags to be unified too](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109827/combine-flag-and-edit-queues-from-main-and-meta-on-se-2-0-sites).

Comment: Any chance of adding suggested edits to meta sites?

Comment: So [Jon Ericson](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1438/jon-ericson) seems to have suggested this over 3 years ago - has there been any progress towards this being allowed/possible?

Comment: Hi, is this happening ever? It's been six years.

Comment: Why not simply remove the ‘edit’ link? It prevents the confusion.

Answer (score 56):

I like to edit where I go, and hate seeing the posts in need of attention.  It's just frustrating to be able to fix posts everywhere, except on the SE Meta sites.  It actually gives less motivation to check on them (and decreases the potential to earn badges on them).

Answer (score 1):

Mostly because the per-site metas are generally low traffic -- some of them count daily visits in the *dozens*.

That means the moderators will have to do the work, since the 10k site users are the only ones that can even see this queue. And on many sites, like say Bicycles -- there are exactly zero users at this rep level, even after many months.

https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all

(highest rep on Bicycles as of the time I am writing is 5.6k)

We were uncomfortable adding Yet Another Queue for Moderators to Look At across every site in the network.

Comment: Maybe the edit queue need to be visible to the top n% of users or all users with over 10K (the the opiton that gives the most users) to cope with sites like bicycles.

Comment: The edits could show up in the same edit queue as edits on the main site (and be highlighted in the top bar like the edits there).

Comment: Just integrate it into the queue on the main site if it's low-traffic! As you noted, there's not a lot of high-rep users on SE 2.0 sites, so it's already a moderator task.

Comment: Am I to understand that once a user reaches 2000 rep, they _can_ edit other people's posts on meta sites?

Comment: Can this **at the very least** be made a configuration option. Meta.Stackoverflow.com has no problems getting enough reviewers, even on its meta.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think you may have commented on the wrong post, this defector has his hands full [working for the Dark Side](http://blog.codinghorror.com/civilized-discourse-construction-kit/) nowadays...old habits die hard?

Comment: @Cupcake: I know where he's at now. The comment is more directed at a general audience.

Comment: What if they would have a complete queue where all of their todo tasks would be summed up?

Comment: Related: [Allow suggested edits on site metas and show them in the main site queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129033/162827)