# Combine flag and edit queues from main and meta on SE 2.0 sites

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderator-tools, per-site-meta, flag-queue

#### Abstract

There's no need to have two flag queues (one for meta, and one for main) for moderators to check.  There's also no need to have two edit queues, if suggested edits were allowed on meta sites.  We should have one flag queue and one edit queue for both main and meta SE 2.0 sites.

#### Background

Most of these sites have a low traffic level and low participation.  How low traffic are they?  Moderators get pinged in their global inbox for questions on Meta sites because we're desperately trying to make sure that any traffic is successful.  Our meta traffic is picking up rapidly, but it's nowhere near the point that it's sensible to check meta's  flag queue.

#### The Problem

The flag and edit queues are currently separate on the meta and main sites.  This reduces the flag handling time, and is yet another queue for mods to check.  The undesirability of a *separate* edit queue is used to justify the [lack of suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87890/why-cant-i-suggest-edits-on-se-meta-sites) on meta sites.

#### The Solution

The flag queue on meta should be integrated with the main site flag queue.  Additionally, suggested edits should be implemented on meta, and this queue integrated with that of the main site.

Comment: Note: SO and MSO do not apply here.

Comment: I think you meant that it *increases* the flag handling time?

Comment: How often do you visit your meta(s)?  While you can rely on the notifications to tell you about *new questions*, they won't tell you about other changes like new answers (or, currently, flags).  If you're visiting meta regularly I don't understand the need; if you're not visiting meta regularly, maybe there are reasons beyond flags to do so?

Answer (score 21):

Implemented.

In the mod dashboard (flags queue), if on main site and the meta has flags, the number of flags will be shown and the meta flag queue is linked. With a meta site, the reverse happens.

With you in the next build.

Comment: Is the total supposed to show both flag counts combined? On Workplace right now we have one on both main/meta and the total count is only 1 (but the toggle works in the mod menu).

Comment: @enderland - meta would show the # of flags on main, main would show the # of flags on meta.

Comment: So not a combined count? Will this show zero flags on main if for example main is 0 and meta is 5? Or vice versa?

Comment: @enderland - right, it isn't combined. If there are no flags on main, there will be no link - that section won't show up.

Comment: To clarify - only the flag-related part of this feature-request is being implemented, and not the suggested-edit-related part?

Comment: @Air - that's correct (see details on [the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/277234/140505) from bluefeet)

Comment: When does this go live? (so that I know how long I need to keep refreshing meta as well as main to check for new flags)

Comment: @randal'thor It's live now, at least on SO.

Comment: @rand - it is live now.

Comment: @enderland it took me a while to find this.  It's on the flags page over in the right column -- "N meta flags" on main.

Comment: So the indicator is only on a specific page, and it's off-screen to boot (with a browser window size that allows me to fit two windows side by side)? That  isn't very useful. Why not combine the flag indicators like the request asked for?

Comment: @Oded Ah, I missed it before since I was assuming the blue number in the top bar would reflect both main and meta flag counts (or there'd be two numbers up there). Got to agree with Gilles here - would it be possible to amend it so that the total flag count (main plus meta) is visible on any page and we don't have to keep refreshing two pages, one on main and one on meta, in order to spot new flags?

Comment: Related: [In the flag queue, make it more obvious when there are flags on the per-site-meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300737/335251)

Answer (score 13):

While we didn't have a single flag on meta.crypto in all time¹, according to our moderator tools (though I think I did flag something before becoming moderator), **I think this is a good idea.**

Not being able to edit on metas where I don't have the required reputation (and where I'm not moderator) already did hinder me some times.

Suggesting edits on meta pages should not give any reputation, of course.

---

¹This has changed since I originally answered the question: now (march 2014) we collected 11 flags in total.

Comment: Indeed, the low flag volume on meta is exactly why the queues should be merged. Moderators are very unlikely to even see flags on meta because they're not used to looking for them.

Answer (score 11):

I agree and disagree with parts of this request.  First off, I don't agree with mixing the suggested edit queues - on large sites like Stack Overflow it'd be incredibly confusing to users when they get a MSO suggested edit, so I'm going to [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) that portion of this request.

But when it comes to the flags, since those are only seen by moderators I agree that it would be helpful to provide a [link with a count of the number of flags in the flag dashboard on the main site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277171/make-flags-from-child-meta-sites-appear-in-the-main-sites-menu-and-vice-versa/277172#277172) (suggested by ChrisF).  That being said, I'm not a dev so I'm not sure how much work would be involved to do this on both the main and meta sites, so I'll [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) this and write it up internally to see if we can get it implemented.

Comment: Good points, we definitely don't want the average main-site reviewer seeing Meta edits.

Comment: I suggested the latter option here - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277171/make-flags-from-child-meta-sites-appear-in-the-main-sites-menu-and-vice-versa/277172#277172

Comment: @ChrisF Credit given. :)

Comment: I wasn't fishing for credit, honest :)

Comment: Implemented latter bit. In the next build. //cc @ChrisF