# Allow suggested edits on site metas and show them in the main site queue

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, review, per-site-meta

Suggested edits are disabled on per-site metas, which means that only users with full edit privileges (>2k rep on graduated sites or >1000 rep on public betas) can edit posts on a site meta. This has been declared [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) by Jeff Atwood a while ago, [with the justification that another queue moderators and high-rep users would have to keep watch on would be a bad idea](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97371/151385).

But as already mentioned in comments there, the ideal solution would be to just add the suggested edits on the meta to the queue on the main site. That way there would be no additional queue, and the meta sites would be editable by anyone like all the main sites.

The whole SE network trains its users to expect being able to edit any post, disabling that functionality silently on the meta sites breaks the user expectations and only leads to confusion. It also drastically reduces the number of users able to edit on site metas for many sites.

I don't know if there are any technical aspects that make this solution difficult to implement, but from an external perspective just adding the suggested edits to the main queue seems like a good solution to this problem.

Comment: It depends on the public beta, the threshold can be 1000 in [some places](http://french.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit).

Comment: Wouldn't mixing edits for the meta and main sites create at least as much confusion as not having suggested edits on meta sites?

Comment: This was already previously requested at [Combine flag and edit queues from main and meta on SE 2.0 sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109827/combine-flag-and-edit-queues-from-main-and-meta-on-se-2-0-sites); that part of the request was marked [tag:status-declined] in Taryn's answer.

Answer (score 17):

It's very confusing to be able to edit on main but not meta.

It looks like we have most of the pieces of a solution in place already, so providing this shouldn't be nearly as hard as it would have been back when you asked this question.  SE, let's finish it please!

There is a "meta reviews" review link on main sites:

[image: screenshot: review dropdown]

Clicking on it takes you to the meta reviews page, which shows a "suggested edits" queue:

[image: screenshot]

But, on a site where I don't have the edit privilege, I still can't actually propose an edit on meta:

[image: error message]

Not being able to propose edits on meta is sometimes frustrating.  We now have the machinery to help those proposed edits get seen.  So let's enable them.

Specifically, we need to:

- Enable edit submissions on all post types on meta.  (They are currently possible only on tag wikis, according to that error message.)
- Make sure the "Meta Reviews" queue lights up when there are reviews waiting.  It appears that this does not happen now.  We should set the threshold to be very low, because reviews on meta are less common than on main.

(I found an example to test that last point with.  Workplace Meta had two items in the close queue, which lit up gray for me on meta.  On main, "Meta Reviews" showed nothing.)

Comment: The only missing piece not specifically mentioned here is that I don't know if the logic for review indicators handles meta review links specifically. If it does, then all is in place; if not, that would need to be coded (although I can't imagine that's terribly complicated).

Comment: @NathanTuggy do you mean the logic to light up "Meta Reviews" on main with the gray/red indicator?  That's a good point; meta reviews are so rare (as far as I know) that I don't know whether it's not wired up or it is but it never triggers on my sites.

Comment: @MonicaCellio: Yes, that's what I'm referring to. As I almost never use the topbar menu to get to reviews, I don't know myself.

Comment: @NathanTuggy edited to make the remaining work more clear.  Thanks for the feedback.