# Don't show the edit option when I can't really edit (mobile apps)

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, edits, android-app, ios-app

Currently in both [iOS app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225138/cannot-edit-posts-on-ios-app) and [android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208471/android-app-should-send-edits-to-edit-queue-if-necessary-rather-than-rejecting-t) when viewing a post on a site where you don't have full edit privilege  (and not your own post) you can still see edit option in the actions menu:

> [image]

So I choose it, invest time in editing the post, click "Submit".... and greeted with the dreaded "Account is not allowed to suggest edits" message: (and the edit is lost for good, no draft)

> [image]

Can the "Edit" option be removed from the menu if I don't have edit privilege on the post, at least until suggested edit will be supported in the apps?

Comment: Wait - the only place that suggested edits are prohibited are per-site meta, no?

Comment: @bmike I'm talking about the iOS and android apps, they currently don't support suggested edits, it's not that they are prohibited.

Comment: Suggested edits are not allowed on per-site meta whether you use the API or the main web interface. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87890/why-cant-i-suggest-edits-on-se-meta-sites and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223885/allow-suggested-edits-on-beta-site-metas

Comment: @bmike yes I know, but it's not really relevant in this request. :)

Comment: I was just trying to rule out an edge case and made that comment before I saw the API limitation. I was having difficulty reproducing your report initially to decide how to vote it :) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just skimming through old feature requests.  We've been doing this for a while now.

Answer (score 5):

I'd rather the edit button open the selected post in the native web browser to allow someone who would normally be allowed to suggest an edit to make that edit if the [API can't handle edits yet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225138/cannot-edit-posts-on-ios-app).

Suppressing the edit entirely seems an overly harsh restriction if it can be accomplished with the native browser. You could even make the item "edit in native browser"

Comment: Fair idea,  thanks! :)