# Time to allow suggested edits on per site metas?

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits, per-site-meta

So I was just answering a question on Ask Ubuntu meta about code formatting and it was brought to my attention that users under 2k cannot even click the edit button to view the formatting.

Looking around I think this was done because metas are low traffic and they didn't want the queue to fill up with suggestions that may never be reviewed and that makes sense. Now though many metas are quite healthy and have dedicated user bases that would review these edits.

My suggestion is to let sites choose to allow suggested edits on metas or not based on their needs. A site like Ask Ubuntu could benefit from this as we have a few users who are quite dedicated but fall below the 2k threshold for whatever reason. Letting them suggest edits could only be a benefit to the site as I see it.

This seemed a popular request back a few years but nothing seems to of came of it.

Related:

[Why is the edit button disabled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81681/why-is-the-edit-button-disabled)

[Why can't I suggest edits on SE meta sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87890/why-cant-i-suggest-edits-on-se-meta-sites)

[Allow suggested edits on site metas and show them in the main site queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129033/allow-suggested-edits-on-site-metas-and-show-them-in-the-main-site-queue)

Comment: I agree, but since the prior request didn't receive any staff response, we do have to mark this as a duplicate, so the request is consolidated in one place: [Allow suggested edits on site metas and show them in the main site queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129033/allow-suggested-edits-on-site-metas-and-show-them-in-the-main-site-queue).

Comment: Please see [How do I get attention for old, unfixed bug reports and feature requests without official responses here on Meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306398).

Comment: @SonictheK-DayHedgehog I understand but perhaps we could find a better duplicate? I don't necessarily agree with adding it to the main review queues, metas seem to already have a queue available for this.

Comment: @Mark Agreed. I feel that this detail should make this request distinct, especially since the queues being on main is the *core* of the other proposal, where it is not with this one.

Comment: Worth mentioning, since it's related: you can see all posts' revisions, and by extension post source, by manually typing in the url `/posts/${postId}/revisions`, where the post Id is the number found in the share dialogue `./q/${postId}/${ownUserId}/`.

Comment: I'd post an answer to that one explaining that you agree with enabling suggested edits but why you disagree with having them on the main site.