# Make flags from child meta sites appear in the main site's menu and vice versa

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags, moderator-tools, per-site-meta

Flags on child meta sites are only shown to the site's mods when they visit meta. On sites whose metas are not very active, this means that it could be several days before a mod notices the flag.

Could we please have a centralized flag menu? I would like to see both meta and main site flags appear in the same place irrespective of which site I happen to be browsing at the time. Perhaps they could be color-coded so that we can know what site (meta or main) they're coming from, but at least, they should all appear in one place.

Answer (score 5):

I'd have a new category of flag on each site's dashboard - "meta" on the main site and "main" on the meta with the total number of flags shown.

There's little point in mixing NAA (say) flags from a main site and a meta site, so just having a single link that takes you to the other site's dashboard where you can process that site's flags would be my preferred solution.

It'd stop meta flags languishing unprocessed.

Comment: Fair enough. All I really want is to be notified of meta flags on the main site as well.

Comment: As there's a "blue diamond" shown on the main site for new meta posts, it would already be an improvement to integrate some "you've got new flags" there at least. Some notification is better than none at all :)

Comment: @Izzy - We don't get that on SO - it'd be far too noisy. I think this solution would work for all sites regardless of their activity level.