# Flags from per-site metas are not forwarded to main anymore

Tags: bug, status-norepro, moderator-tools, per-site-meta, flag-queue

#### [The forwarding of per-site-meta flags to the main site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/277978/255554) is broken.

After a flag of mine on a per-site meta is pending since two months, I got suspicious and flagged one of my own meta posts on a site I moderate. While it appeared in the meta’s flag queue, it did not appear on the main site’s one.

My bets are on the URL change of per-site-metas having something to do with this.

***There is no bug. I misunderstood the feature in question.*** I may post a feature request though.

Comment: I can't see this behaviour - looking on one site you are a moderator on, there appears a link to meta flags on the moderator dashboard, with the count of one flag.

Comment: I have also looked on SO and MSO and both have the correct links.