# Navigating to the edit mode of a not-exist page produces a strange error message

Tags: bug, status-deferred, suggested-edits, per-site-meta

Visiting [meta.tex.stackexchange.com/posts/2603](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/2603) produces "404 error" but visting [meta.tex.stackexchange.com/posts/2603/edit](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/2603/edit) produces "There is a pending suggested edit in the queue, try again in a few minutes." Is it a bug?

### When attempting to visit the page (not in edit mode):

[image]

### When attempting to visit the page (in edit mode):

[image]

Comment: The 404 for http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/posts/2603 might actually be by-design, http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2603 (or "q" instead of "question") works. The really strange thing is the denied edit because there is no pending suggested edit in the queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As doncherry notes, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/2603 isn't a valid URL format for a question on SE, so 404 is completely appropriate.

But for the edit URL, it looks like this is being denied because you don't have the reputation to edit on meta and [suggested edits are turned off on meta sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87890/why-cant-i-suggest-edits-on-se-meta-sites).

Unfortunately, it's giving you the wrong error message. Did you come across a link to that somewhere, or did you just compose the URL manually?

Comment: I composed the URL manually.

Comment: I'm gonna say this is still a bug (if it's still happening; is it still happening?) but realistically there's no good reason to fix it - the UI is telling you that you can't edit the post, so you shouldn't really expect it to do anything useful. It should probably give you a generic 403 or 404 error, or a more descriptive message, but the core message - you can't edit this - is clear.

Comment: @Shog9, I came across this today when I was linked to the edit page from the close banner, where it says "Improve this question".