# When can I edit on meta?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits, meta, per-site-meta

On per-site metas, low-rep users [cannot suggest edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87890/172266).  Are there any other differences in the rules on editing posts on per-site metas or MSE?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no other differences, except (maybe, but it's not limited to editing questions, it applies to posting questions as well) that there are certain tags you cannot edit into (or out of) a question, unless you are a moderator: the red system tags like [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) and [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).