# Per-site metas have a review tab for suggested edits

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, suggested-edits, review

… which is silly because [they don't have suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78223/per-site-metas-dont-have-ability-of-suggested-edits).

This might confuse users into thinking that they *do*, and thus cause them to waste time watching the queue in an attempt to be helpful.

Just think about it. Literally *several* people could be deluding themselves right now.

---

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Where are you seeing it's for suggested edits?

Comment: @random Well, the tab says "suggested edits", and when I click it, it says "these are suggested edits". Sort of exactly [like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/03KKa.png "screenshot").

Comment: Is this tab only for 10k+ users? [I don't see it at all.](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/review)

Comment: @Chris You can't review suggested edits, so yeah, you wouldn't. It's currently tied to 5k I believe.

Comment: @lunboks You're absolutely right. Upvoted.

Comment: @lunboks: I get it with 1.8k on meta.tex.sx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>This will be fixed in the next deploy, that tab will not be visible on child metas.</s>

Actually, looks like suggested edits work on metas now; so this is by design.

Comment: Wait, hold everything. Now that [tag wikis can be edited on each individual per-site meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92219/proposing-tag-wiki-creation-does-not-work-on-meta-sites/121066#121066), doesn't that mean that the queue now has a reason to exist? Suggestions on posts aren't possible, but I'm not sure about wikis or excerpts. I get the "your edit will be placed in a queue" message box, but I haven't actually tried submitting one.

Comment: @lunboks - hmm, looks like you're right.  Wasn't aware of that change, reverting this one.