# People between 500 and 2000 reputation lost the edit button

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits, per-site-meta

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can't I suggest edits on SE meta sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87890/why-cant-i-suggest-edits-on-se-meta-sites)

See also [this question on meta.tex.sx](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2262/5763): I have a rep of 1843 on tex.sx. Yet I get no `edit` button on questions like [this](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2258/5763), only a `retag` one. If I manually edit the link (replacing `edit?tagsonly=true` with `edit`), I get the usual suggested edit dialog (I haven't tested if the dialog really works). It seems the software offers only the retagging but allows the suggested edit anyway. Can we have *both* buttons, please?

**Edit**: I tested the edit dialog: It doesn't complain, but I also get no feedback about a suggested edit, so it seems the software properly throws the edit away.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As was once [explained](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2180/31260) to me at Programmers meta, suggested edits are intentionally disabled at meta:

> This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). Suggested edits are disabled on
>   meta sites, so you will need to have 2,000 reputation before you will
>   see the edit link on other people's posts. The only exception is Meta
>   Stack Overflow which functions as a meta for all Stack Exchange sites
>   and has its own reputation pool.
>
> See
>   [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87890/why-cant-i-suggest-edits-on-se-meta-sites/97371#97371)
>   for Jeff Atwood's explanation of the rationale behind that decision.

Comment: What's confusing is that I get the `edit` button on CW-questions.

Comment: A [properly designed feature](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Gnhaq.png) looks different...

Comment: @MartinSchröder That's the whole point of Community Wiki: Lower requirements for editing to facilitate collaboration. See [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit-community-wiki).

Comment: @DanielBeck see [Per-site metas have a review tab for suggested edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106837/per-site-metas-have-a-review-tab-for-suggested-edits)