# Undoing your own edits within the grace period doesn't delete the revision if the previous editor was Community

Tags: bug, revisions-list, community-user

Okay, here's a fairly obscure one.

Normally, if you edit a post, then undo all your changes again within the grace period (manually that is, [rollback doesn't work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123491/rolling-back-your-own-edits-within-the-grace-period-doesnt-delete-the-revisions)), the revision will be silently deleted.

However, if the last editor was [Community](/users/-1/community), typically because the question was closed as a duplicate, then it doesn't happen, and an empty revision stays behind. Strangely enough, it *has* to be Community; anonymous editors don't count.

An example of these empty revisions [can be seen here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/119911/revisions) (revision 3, click the third button in the left).

Comment: Was playing around with nasty roll-backing, apparently one can rollback to the revision of another question. :S

Comment: @TomWijsman Well that's not terribly relevant, but you should report that.

Comment: Not really, because this can be useful as long as it has no side effects.