# The Way of the Editless Edit: why could this user do a blank edit?

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits

[image]

There are two suggested edits here, and the difference is obvious - there is no edit. [While it was rejected, I see a comment but no actual edit](https://superuser.com/suggested-edits/12674). Is this an odd glitch, or something else?

EDIT: Apparently @satya found that even regular users can do it. So now it's not 'how', it's 'why'.

Comment: Creative way to comment on a question, though.

Comment: It's not restricted to anon.. even regular users can do it. Here's an example: http://superuser.com/posts/238818/revisions (FOR SCIENCE, of course!)

Comment: This was reported quite some time ago, but I can't find the earlier question...

Comment: I think the length check or quality filter check are not active on all sites, maybe there are no filters on Super User?

Comment: @Bolt you probably mean [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133934/what-does-it-mean-when-blank-edits-are-made-to-questions)?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Nope, that's a revision, not an edit suggestion.

Comment: @Sathya was able to suggest on the same question you edited by adding blank spaces `&nbsp;` - maybe that's the case? (please reject :))

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd #no.

Comment: Another example: http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/306869

Comment: We've identified the bug and will fix it tomorrow, hopefully.  It has to do with the site being extra helpful and stripping spaces from a title's ending punctuation, e.g. "How can I do this ?"

Comment: @Gilles your example was perfect, note how the [main question page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202186/how-to-copy-record-using-hibernate-in-java) doesn't have the space, but the [raw revision does](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4202186/revisions).

Comment: @jarrod did this get fixed..?

Comment: Doesn't look like this is possible any longer.

Comment: @Anna but did Jarrod fix the bug, or is the code still stripping away such spaces?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Jarrod sez it should be fixed, and I can't seem to repro it here.

Comment: @AnnaLear OK, taking hiz word then. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This got fixed by Jerrod, as per the comments. Between the status completed and such, self answering to close the loop