# Editing after multiple edits at the same time

Tags: bug, edits, warning

When you attempt to edit a question that has been edited in the same second by two different people (such as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/93452/820)), there is always a warning that "you're editing an old revision", irrespective of which edit you've selected.

Comment: I have a better example: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14439736/revisions two exactly equal edits.

Comment: @rekire That'd be a different bug (if it is one). It does _not_ have the effect I describe here. I admit its warning for one version and not for the other, even though they're the same, is _interesting_. :-)

Comment: This has been reported before. Cant find it though.

Comment: @AshRj which? My original bug or rekire's issue?

Comment: The original one

Comment: @rekire: Your issue does seem to be similar to [What does it mean when blank edits are made to questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133934/147650) except the edits were a second apart instead of 9 months.

Comment: @MarkHurd I asked a seperate question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164491/171881

Answer (score 1):

This eight year old bug does not seem to occur anymore; [editing the almost-newest revision](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/93452/edit/4aa90d8e-2280-4385-b177-9735d82f5de0) shows the warning:

[image]

but [editing the newest revision](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/93452/edit/0c252198-393a-41f9-8ecf-0c5155ccc3e4) doesn't show it.