# Should an exactly equal edit be dropped?

Tags: bug, edits

I just improved an answer which was one second later edited by another user with the same actions, so that the diff is completely empty. I think the later edit should been dropped automatically.

Here is the question I'm talking about: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14439736/revisions

Comment: This is basically a dupe of any bug report about the existing race condition in editing; opening the editor on a post at the same time can lead to one edit overwriting another. In your case the conflicting edit happened to be the same, but the situation is exactly the same.

Comment: Related: [Unconditionally ask for confirmation before submitting an edit if one was just submitted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99535)