# Socket live-updates shows deleted tag instead of actual tags when retagged

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, live-refresh

I have been watching [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) for few minutes now and it seems that [casperOne ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/140951/casperone) [deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/211052/revisions) [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) from that post. However, in `/questions/tagged/discussion/` it looks it just shows the deleted tag instead of current tag(s).

[image]

Comment: Just tried it with this question; no repro. Maybe he did accidentally delete the wrong tag (which caused the live update), and then corrected his mistake within the grace period (which doesn't cause another live update AFAIK).

Comment: @luboks how did you delete "modified" box? I saw you retagged this question, but it has disappeared now. Where?

Comment: Unicorn magic, fairy dust, and also I undid my own edit within the grace period.

Comment: @lun you just rolled back ?

Comment: I specifically didn't because of [this bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123491/rolling-back-your-own-edits-within-the-grace-period-doesnt-delete-the-revisions). Gotta do it manually.

Comment: @lunk ah, I didn't even know that revision is deleted in this period

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case a tag edit was made, rolled back, and then another tag edit was made:

```
Date            Method  Uri                 Route
2012-04-05 13:14:43 POST    /posts/211052/edit-tags Posts/EditTags
2012-04-05 13:14:37 GET /posts/211052/edit-tags Posts/EditTags
2012-04-05 13:14:30 POST    /posts/211052/rollback  Posts/Rollback
2012-04-05 13:14:21 GET /posts/211052/edit-tags Posts/EditTags
2012-04-05 13:13:48 POST    /posts/211052/edit-tags Posts/EditTags
2012-04-05 13:13:47 GET /posts/211052/edit-tags Posts/EditTags
```

The rollback triggered the live update since the original post contained the discussion tag.