# What exactly are 'non-tag-wiki posts'?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, per-site-meta

I noticed that I cannot edit [this meta question](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/q/56/99). The tooltip explains  that

> Suggested edits are not allowed on non-tag-wiki posts on meta sites

After searching I found [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87890/164138) and [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78223/164138) that says that this is by design. I do get the reason why I can't edit (not enough rep), my problem is that the tooltip explanation is not very clear to me. What exactly is meant by 'non-tag-wiki posts'?. Does it mean that if someone with enough rep adds a 'wiki' tag to the question then I will be able to edit the post?

Comment: See: [So what's this “tag wiki” thing?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57992/so-whats-this-tag-wiki-thing) (non-tag-wiki is everything that's not a "tag wiki")

Comment: @Yannis Thanks for clearing that up! I get it now. Maybe it's just me, but I do think the explanation tooltip should be rephrased to something simpler. For example: You cannot edit questions or answers on meta sites until you have 1000 reputation points.