# Will having more than 1000 reputation points allow me to edit per site Meta posts as well?

Tags: support, reputation, edits, suggested-edits, per-site-meta

Currently [suggested edits are not permitted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78223/per-site-metas-dont-have-ability-of-suggested-edits) in the baby meta sites (per meta sites).

If my reputation exceeds 1000 in the main site, will I be permitted to edit (not suggested edit but direct edit) per site meta posts too?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, when you gain [edit privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) on the main site, you also get the ability to edit posts on the meta site as well.

For sites in beta, the current reputation requirement is 1000 points, where as for graduated sites, you need 2000 points to gain this privilege.

Comment: Are you really saying that getting 2,000 rep on Meta SE gets you edit privileges on all other metas? I ask because the asker seems to have clarified that as their question via a comment. I think you are saying getting 2,000 on any Main gets you edit privileges on its Meta which is a different question.

Comment: @PolyGeo No, 2000 reps on a main site will give you edit privilege on the meta site of that particular main site only. Reps on Meta.SE has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Your use of main and meta is clear, and I agree with what you say, but I am finding the question unclear.  It is probably the baby meta term that made it hard to follow.