# Answering a question on a meta site with 30+ answers shouldn't tell me I can edit existing answers

Tags: bug, answers

The Programming Puzzles & Code Golf meta site has a [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/) for proposing new questions; as such, it has a lot of answers. If I press "Answer This Question", I get an alert warning me about the number of answers; but the alert also says `please note that you can click the edit link on any of these answers to improve them.`

As far as I know, that's not true for meta, so that part of the message shouldn't be there.

Comment: sandboxes arn't really a 'feature' but a workaround. Also, meta questions could have too many answers too... in theory.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Correct, but that's not what this issue is about though. What I'm saying is that it shouldn't be telling me that I can edit existing answers to improve them, because that's not true on meta sites.

Comment: Oh! Actually, I think you can - its suggested edits you can't do, no?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Oh, didn't realise you could. So yes, it's only suggested edits you can't do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's [*suggested edits* that you can't do on per site metas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78223/per-site-metas-dont-have-ability-of-suggested-edits) — if you can do edits on your own on main sites, you can do edits on the appropriate per site meta. As such, the alert isn't entirely incorrect.